# Linux - show screen logs on multiple screens?

Tags: linux, centos, gnu-screen

I have a problem with `screen`. Basically I want it to make one log per screen, for example screen #1 will be `screenlog.1` & screen #2 will be `screenlog.2` - you get the memo.

Anyhow, what happens is that when I launch screen using:

```
screen -SL screen1
```

(The `-L` parameter is because I need to force it to make logs) it only logs the first screen, not the rest 2-5 screens. I've tried using the `.screenrc` file with the `logfile` parameter, it works - but just changes the name of `screenlog.0`, which isn't really what I want.

Any idea how I would go about this?

Additonal information: CentOS 6.3 (64bit).
Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06.

Comment: Or use `tmux` which makes all of these automation projects so much less painful than `screen` ever did.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can log the output of multiple screen sessions in separate log files:

1. Start a screen session using `screen -S <preferred-name-of-session>`
2. Attach the screen using & then set the logfile of the screen using the command:
    `Ctrl + a :logfile <name-of-log-file>`
3. Start the screen logging by running `Ctrl + a H`
4. Execute the required program & then detach the screen

This might look like a lot of work everytime but once you start using it, it becomes very handy!

Answer (score 2):

You may be experiencing buffering of the log output.

I locally tested both with and without screen name and received the expected screenlog.0 and .1 and .2 etc. Each log corresponded to the contents of each window. There is a buffer before it gets written to disk

Reference flush secs:
http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Logging

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [what splaer said](https://serverfault.com/a/536754/32986) (which is probably what's going on here), you might want to use [`script`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/script) to record your sessions if `screen` is giving you trouble.

The convenience of `screen -L` is nice to have, but if it's giving you trouble `script` is a handy workaround (and if you ever find yourself on a machine *without* `screen` -- they do still exist sadly -- it's likely `script` is still going to be there).